# Посчитать выражение с помощью рекурсивной функции и без

Tags: c++

```
Xi = ((i+1)/(i^2+1)*Xi-1) - Xi-2*Xi-3                  
X0 = X1 = 0, X2 = 1.5
```

(i-индекс). На ввод подаётся индекс от 3 и до бесконечности. Задача: посчитать Xi.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double fnc(double n, double n1, double ny0, double ny1, double ny2, double ny3) {
    if (n1 > n) return ny2;
    else return fnc(n, n1 + 1, ny1, ny2, ((n1 + 1) / (n1 * n1 + 1) * ny2) - (ny1 * ny0), 0);
}

int main()
{
    double n;
    cout << "Enter n: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << endl;
    double c = fnc(n, 3.00, 0.00, 0.00, 1.50, 0.00);
    cout << c << endl;
    
    double ny0 = 0.00, ny1 = 0.00, ny2 = 1.50, ny3 = 0.00;
    for (double n1 = 3.00; n1 <= n; n1++) {
        ny3 = ((n1 + 1) / (n1 * n1 + 1) * ny2) - (ny1 * ny0);
        ny0 = ny1;
        ny1 = ny2;
        ny2 = ny3;
        ny3 = 0;
    }
    cout << ny2;
}
```

С помощью рекурсивной функции посчитать получилось. Вопрос, считается ли то, что считается с помощью цикла for, методом без рекурсии? Если нет, то как можно посчитать без рекурсии?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То что считается в for, является интеративным подходом, так как цикл for выполняет циклическую обработку данных. Так как рекурсия это рекурсивная обработка, когда функция вызывает саму себя, пока не дойдет до некой базы рекурсии.

Также можно заметить что при рекурсии мы как бы "спускаемся" вглубь от необходимого значения до базы, и при итеративном "идем" вверх, от базовых значений до какого-то ограничения, в вашем случае до n

Answer (score 1):

"Рекурсия" означает, что какая-то функция вызывает саму себя (возможно не напрямую).

В варианте с циклом такого нет, значит и рекурсии нет.